# Union Select two queries subtract from particular data

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I need to build a query which performs subtraction on basis of client name here is my query I built for getting data

```
SELECT invoice.client_name, (Sum(invoice.freight_rate)+Sum(invoice.total_basic_amount)+Sum(invoice.delivery_rate)) 
    FROM invoice GROUP BY invoice.client_name 
UNION SELECT client_name,(Sum(payments.payment_received)) 
    FROM payments GROUP BY client_name
```

And here is what I get as an output

```
client_name   |   Expr1001
John   |   2500
John   |   3630
MAc   |   12000
MAc   |   15300
```

What I need is

```
client_name   |   Expr1001
John   |   1130
MAc   |   3300
```

Which is simple subtraction of both query.
I already asked this question before and I got some good responses but they aren't working and now nobody replies to it. Here is what I got from them.

```
SELECT invoice.client_name, (Sum(invoice.freight_rate)+Sum(invoice.total_basic_amount)+Sum(invoice.delivery_rate)-Sum(payments.payment_received)) AS Expr1
FROM invoice, payments
WHERE (([invoice].[client_name]=[payments].[client_name]))
GROUP BY invoice.client_name;
```

This query returns some very strange output which is

```
client_name   |   Expr1001
John   |   2260
MAc   |   18600
```

I'm Attaching the db file here is the link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dbxHzXDbfe8l1ZDN9ZxZo7Rs1UImhV8r/view?usp=share_link

Comment: SO discourages links to file downloads. Many will not download files or files are not compatible with user app. All info needed to evaluate issue should be in question. Edit question to show sample data as formatted text table.

Comment: Should not save item pricing data in Invoice table. This is duplicating data in invoice_items.

Answer (score 0):

You need subqueries:

```sql
Select 
    Charges.client_name, 
    TotalCharges-TotalPayments As Total

From

    (Select 
        invoice.client_name, 
        Sum(CCur([invoice].[freight_rate]))+Sum(CCur([invoice].[total_basic_amount]))+Sum(CCur([invoice].[delivery_rate])) As TotalCharges
    From 
        invoice
    Group By 
        invoice.client_name) As Charges

Inner Join

    (Select 
         payments.client_name, 
         Sum(CCur([payment_received])) As TotalPayments
    From 
         payments
    Group By 
         payments.client_name) As Payments

On Charges.client_name = Payments.client_name
```

and you should not store amount as text ...

Comment: Probably need LEFT (or RIGHT) JOIN because possibly not all invoices will have associated payments. Client_Name fields in Invoices and Payments should just hold client ID which means need to include Clients table to retrieve name.

Comment: nope this returns the same output as John 2260 and MAc 18600

Comment: @June7 No there is client_name in both tables not id.

Comment: I have attached db link in question please check it

Comment: Well, name should not be in both tables. Should be a Clients table and then client ID should be saved.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple invoice and payment records for each client. This means must aggregate each table's data then join those datasets.

```
SELECT I.client_name, amt - pmt AS Total
FROM (SELECT client_name, Sum(total_basic_amount) AS amt FROM invoice GROUP BY client_name) AS I 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT client_name, Sum(payment_received) AS pmt FROM payments GROUP BY client_name) AS P 
ON I.client_name = P.client_name;
```

Or this version:

```
SELECT invoice.client_name, Sum(total_basic_amount)-Max(pmt) AS Total 
FROM Invoice LEFT JOIN (SELECT client_name, Sum(payment_received) AS pmt FROM Payments GROUP BY client_name) AS P 
ON invoice.client_name = P.client_name 
GROUP BY invoice.client_name;
```